# Spring MVC 3.1: Problems in using SimpleUrlHandlerMapping and generic base controller

Tags: java, spring

With spring 3.1 i miss the functionality of using a generic base controller for default-url-mapping. Regard following example:

```
<bean id="appleController" class="de.mw.mwdata.core.web.control.GenericEntityController" />
<bean id="peachController" class="de.mw.mwdata.core.web.control.GenericEntityController" />

<bean id="urlMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping" >
    <property name="alwaysUseFullPath" value="true"/>
    <property name="mappings">
      <props>
        <prop key="/admin/apple/list.htm">appleController</prop>
        <prop key="/admin/peach/list.htm">peachController</prop>
        <prop key="/admin/strawberry/list.htm">strawberryController</prop>
      </props>
    </property>
</bean> 

<mvc:annotation-driven />

<context:component-scan base-package="de.mw.mwdata.app.admin.web.control" >
</context:component-scan>
```

Here the relevant code-snippets for GenericEntityController and strawberryController:

```
    @RequestMapping("/admin/**")
public class GenericEntityController<E extends AbstractEntity> {

    ...

    @RequestMapping(value = "**/list.htm", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView list( final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response ) {  
        ...
    }

}

package de.mw.mwdata.app.admin.web.control;
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/admin/strawberry/")
public class StrawberryController extends GenericEntityController<Strawberry> {
    ...
    }
}
```

So before spring 3.1 and with SimpleUrlHandlerMapping i had two controller-instances (of GenericEntityController) for contextpath apple and peach and one annotated 
controller-instance of StrawberryController. The mapping to the /list.htm-method was done by the @RequestMapping particularly on method-level.
My question: in spring-mvc 3.1 SimpleUrlHandlerMapping doesn't work anymore with annotated @RequestMapping. I get following exception:

```
Cannot map 'peachController' bean method 
public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView de.mw.mwdata.core.web.control.GenericEntityController.list(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)
to {[/admin/**/list.htm],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}: There is already 'appleController' bean method
public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView de.mw.mwdata.core.web.control.GenericEntityController.list(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse) mapped.
```

How can i replace this configuration in spring 3.1 ?

Answer (score 1):

Your apple and peach controllers are both trying to map to the same paths since they use the same backing class. If you are going to use annotations for your controllers, you should make those 2 different classes. If you want to avoid that, and want the same logic to execute for both apples and peaches, I would suggest making an AppleAndPeachController class and then only having one bean defined in your XML instead of two.

With either approach, you should no longer need your SimpleUrlHandlerMapping since Spring will automatically create the handler mapping based off your annotated controllers.

If you want to map multiple paths to the same controller, @RequestMapping can take an array of strings as a parameter, like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value={"/admin/apple", "/admin/peach", "/admin/morefruit"})
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, thank you very much for the quick answer.
Yes, currently they map both to the same path and unfortunately to the same class: because of RequestMappingHandlerMapping in spring 3.1 now for every controller with @RequestMapping-annotations. Thats the problem !
Before spring 3.1 The simpleUrlHandlerMapping i defined was responsible for that, and it doesnt map to the same path/class. Instead there was a 1-to-1-mapping to every created instance of my GenericEntityController. Unfortunately i need one controller-instance of my GenericEntityController for every "fruit" because of "fruit-specific" services injected to the relevant controller.
So how can i map several URL-paths to different instances of the same generic base controller-class ? 
Thx again for every tip...